# Show that the set $W$ of all vectors that are of the form $x=(a,0,a,0)$ is subspace of $R^4$.

Tags: vectors

The task is: [Task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4kuY.png)

Show that the set W of all vectors that are of the form x=(a,0,a,0) is subspace of R^4 by finding a set of spanning vectors of W. What is the geometric form?

My approach was to pick values for `a` that belongs to R and make 4 vectors. Let `v1=(1,0,1,0)`,`v2=(2,0,2,0)`,`v3=(3,0,3,0)` and `v4=(4,0,4,0)`.  Then I made a matrix of them:

```
1 2 3 4
0 0 0 0
1 2 3 4
0 0 0 0
```

I used RREF on that matrix, and got the span (-2,0,0,0),(0,-3,0,0), (0,0,0,-4).

Did I do the task correctly. And how can I know which geometric shape is that?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Not even close. Once you were done computing the RREF, it looks like you tried to extract a basis for its _null space_ instead of for the column space of the original matrix, but you didn’t do that correctly, either. If you show the details of your work, then someone can explain just exactly where you are going wrong.

Comment: Thank you. I will double check and write again the whole solution.

Answer (score 1):

$W=R^2$ is a  vector space  and being a subset of $R^4$ it is a subspace. In terms of basis; $\{(1,0,0,0), (0,0,1,0)\}$ is the standard basis of $W$ and this basis is contained in the standard basis of $R^4$, and thus this way also you can conclude that $W$ is a subspace of $R^4$.

Comment: Kindly upvote if you are ok with the answer.